# Take webcam snapshot in java without JMF?

Tags: java, webcam

I was wondering what I would need to read up on in order to take a snapshot with java?

I don't want to use any external libraries... I want to do it all myself for the purpose of learning. If you could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/) -- superb lib, which works under both Linux and Windows. That is an external lib, but it is open source and thus you can grab their code and see how it is implemented.